# Moving from South to Django 1.7 migrations: swappable dependency

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have a project written with Django 1.6 and that uses South migrations, and I trying to move it to Django 1.7. So I started from the instructions indicated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south).

1. Deleted `south` from `INSTALLED_APPS`.
2. Removed old migrations files.
3. Ran `./manage.py makemigrations`.

At this point I got `django.db.migrations.graph.CircularDependencyError`.

Here are my models:

`customer.models.py`:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
    )

class Department(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        'customer.Customer',
        related_name='departments',
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
    )

class Representative(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'userprofile.User',
        related_name='representatives',
    )
    department = models.ForeignKey(
        'customer.Department',
        related_name='representatives',
    )
```

`userprofile.models.py`:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    customers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'customer.Customer',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

That caused in initial migration for `customer` application a swappable dependency:

```
dependencies = [
    migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
]
```

As it was recommended [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22932#comment:4), I edited initial migration for `userprofile` and commented lines related with customer:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0001_initial'),
        #('customer', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=128, error_messages={b'min_length': 'El campo "Nombres" debe tener al menos %(limit_value)d caracteres (actualmente tiene %(show_value)d).'}, verbose_name='nombres', validators=[django.core.validators.MinLengthValidator(3)])),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=128, error_messages={b'min_length': 'El campo "Apellidos" debe tener al menos %(limit_value)d caracteres (actualmente tiene %(show_value)d).'}, verbose_name='apellidos', validators=[django.core.validators.MinLengthValidator(3)])),
                ('email', models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=75, verbose_name='correo electr\xf3nico')),
                #('customers', models.ManyToManyField(to='customer.Customer', null=True, verbose_name='clientes relacionados', blank=True)),
            ],
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),
    ]
```

ran `./manage.py migrate` and created another migration that adds a customer field:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('customer', '0001_initial'),
        ('userprofile', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='customers',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(to='customer.Customer', null=True, verbose_name='clientes relacionados', blank=True),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
    ]
```

But when I run `./manage.py migrate userprofile --fake`, I get an error

```
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

On the other hand, without this migration my tests fail:

```
OperationalError: no such table: userprofile_user_customers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My error was to run `./manage.py makemigrations userprofile`, instead of running `./manage.py makemigrations userprofile --empty`. In the first case Django understood it like a migration that adds `contracts` field (which it is) and for the second case, if I ran `./manage.py migrate userprofile` it fails with:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "userprofile_user_customers" already exists
```

So I had to:

1. Copy the content of the last migration:

   ```
   class Migration(migrations.Migration):

       dependencies = [
           ('customer', '0001_initial'),
           ('userprofile', '0001_initial'),
       ]

       operations = [
           migrations.AddField(
               model_name='user',
               name='customers',
               field=models.ManyToManyField(to='customer.Customer', null=True, verbose_name='clientes relacionados', blank=True),
               preserve_default=True,
           ),
       ]
   ```
2. Delete that migration.
3. Run `./manage.py makemigrations userprofile --empty`.
4. Paste and run `./manage.py migrate userprofile --fake`.